# Congruence of skew-symmetric matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-congruences, skew-symmetric-matrices

> Prove that every matrix congruent to a skew symmetric matrix is skew symmetric.

My work-

[image]

How do I prove that the transforming matrix $P$ is always orthogonal? Please help.